# How do I open apps up in windows rather than full screen with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, user-interface, windows-8-apps

I have had my Windows 8 laptop (HP Split- with detachable screen) for a few months now, and I am getting increasingly frustrated by the fact that whenever I open up an application, it automatically opens up 'full screen', and prevents you being able to see/ use more than one app at a time without having to close the full screen one down (in particular, things like Word/ Adobe reader).

I have had a look for a setting that would allow me to revert this to how it was in Windows 7- where you start off on the Desktop, and any application you open runs from there- with a little icon on the start bar to select it/ navigate to it, but can't find one. Windows 8 will do this for applications such as my web browser or iTunes, but I can't seem to find a way to make it open any Microsft applications or Adobe Reader in a 'windowed' mode rather than in full screen mode.

Does anyone know if there is a 'fix' available for this, or a way to change the settings to allow apps to open up in a windowed mode rather than full screen mode?

Comment: Well until you mention Word and Adobe it seems like you were talking about Modern UI applications.  Are you 100% your not able to place them in Window mode, use the keyboard shortcut, if you need to.

Comment: I have not found a way to do so- despite looking in every 'settings' menu I can find that looks like it might be relevant... That's why I'm asking... It seems that since my computer has a detachable screen, it has been designed for use as a touchscreen, but since it does also have a keyboard attachment (which has an additional hard drive inside), it is clearly also intended for use as a laptop, but the options for viewing applications seems to be limited to viewing them as you would when using the 'tablet' (detached screen), with no option to view them using the laptop...

Comment: Do you know the difference between a desktop application being in full window mode and a modern UI application?

Comment: I know that you could make a 'normal' windowed application appear in full screen mode in Windows 7 (and previous versions), i.e. so that the whole screen would be filled with the window, and you wouldn't see the 'window' bar at the top, with the title of the application and the minimise, maximise and close buttons on the far right. The issue that I'm having (and I understand it to be a design feature of Windows 8) is that these applications are appearing as they would on a tablet (i.e. full screen mode, with no 'window' bar, or minimise/ maximise/ close buttons).

Comment: But since my computer also has the possibility to be used as a laptop, as well as a tablet, I would have thought that there would be some feature to allow me to set the programs to work in a 'windowed' mode, as they would normally on a laptop, rather than as a touch screen 'app'.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.  You can take a screenshot of your entire desktop by doing "PrtScn" this will help me get an idea of whats going on.  The shortcut to get out of full screen mode in word is the `Esc` button same for reader.

Answer (score 0):

I think "windowed" apps weren't possibly until the Windows 8.1 update....
At least that was the case with my Samsung ATIV 700T (convertible laptop, similar your to HP Split)

Comment: They still are not possible.  He is running classic desktop applications based on the usage off Word and Adobe.

Comment: Usage of the words "Word" and "Adobe Reader" does not indicate classic desktop applications. The standard Adobe Reader preinstalled on my computer is the modern UI application, and multiple apps can be "windowed" side by side since Windows 8.1 update

Comment: Neither of those applications have Windows Store versions except perhaps `Adobe Reader` and while it does its not called `Adobe Reader`.  Word at this time isn't a `Windows Store` application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd party tool called [ModernMix](http://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/) which allows you to run Windows Store Apps in a Window on the Desktop:

[image]

with Windows 8 and 8.1.

Comment: Would it allow you to run Apps that weren't purchased through Winows Store on the Desktop too? Or is it just ones you've bought from there?

Comment: All new "Metro" apps can be run in a Window with this tool.